# Como cargar correctamente un Select de Materialize 1.0 desde JQuery?

Tags: materialize

Al aplicar la clase browser-default se cargan los option correctamente, pero no logro trabajar con el select de materialize cargando option desde jquery.

```
<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4">
    <select  name="prim" id="prim"  class="validate">
      <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select --</option>
       <option value="1">hola</option>
       <option value="2">mundo</option>
    </select>
  <label for="prim">Primero</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4"> 
    <select name="seg" id="seg" class="validate">
    </select>
    <label for="seg">Segundo</label>
  </div>
```

M.AutoInit();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
});

$('#prim').change(function()
{ 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        $('#seg').append($('<option>',
        {
            value: i,
            text : "Option "+i 
        }));
    }
    $('#seg').formSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede estar **en el orden en que agregas las librerías**. Si agregas jQuery primero el código funciona:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
});

$('#prim').change(function()
{ 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        $('#seg').append($('<option>',
        {
            value: i,
            text : "Option "+i 
        }));
    }
    $('#seg').formSelect();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4">
  <select name="prim" id="prim" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">hola</option>
    <option value="2">mundo</option>
  </select>
  <label for="prim">Primero</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4">
  <select name="seg" id="seg" class="validate">
  </select>
  <label for="seg">Segundo</label>
</div>
```

Si agregas jQuery después, no funciona:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
});

$('#prim').change(function()
{ 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        $('#seg').append($('<option>',
        {
            value: i,
            text : "Option "+i 
        }));
    }
    $('#seg').formSelect();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4">
  <select name="prim" id="prim" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">hola</option>
    <option value="2">mundo</option>
  </select>
  <label for="prim">Primero</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6 m4 l4">
  <select name="seg" id="seg" class="validate">
  </select>
  <label for="seg">Segundo</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Muy agradecido amigo... Diste en el clavo. Soy nuevo en el foro. Solo se califica aceptando la respuesta? no hay como darte 10 estrellas?

Comment: @CRUZVARGAS me alegro de haberte ayudado. Puedes votar a favor pulsando en la flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba. Creo que como tienes pocos puntos no se hará efectivo el voto a favor, pero lo hará automáticamente cuando tengas los puntos suficientes... Puedes por tanto pulsar dicha flecha y listo.